# Global variable trouble

Tags: jquery, scope, global-variables

I have this global function I wrote:

```
    var aSpecimen = 0;

$(function(){
  function prodCarousel(div){
    $(div).find('li.next a').click(function() {
        $(div).find('ul.display li').hide();
        $(div).find('.viewer ul li.img').siblings().removeClass('viewerOn');
        aSpecimen = aSpecimen + 1;

        if (aSpecimen == $(div).find('ul.display li').length + 0)
            aSpecimen = 0;

        if (aSpecimen == $(div).find('.img').length + 0)
            aSpecimen = 0;

        $(div).find('ul.display li:eq(' + aSpecimen + ')').fadeIn("fast");

        $(div).find('.img:eq(' + aSpecimen + ')').addClass('viewerOn');

        return false;
    });

    $('li.prev a').click(function() {
        $(div).find('ul.display li').hide();
        $(div).find('.viewer ul li.img').siblings().removeClass('viewerOn');
        aSpecimen = aSpecimen - 1;

         if (aSpecimen == -1) aSpecimen = $(div).find('ul.display li').length - 1;

        $(div).find('ul.display li:eq(' + aSpecimen + ')').fadeIn("fast");
        $(div).find('.viewer ul li.img:eq(' + aSpecimen + ')').addClass('viewerOn');
        return false;
    });
  }
});
```

I am attempting to call it using the following:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

      function prodNav(div, self){
        $("#product1, #product2").empty();
        $('#product'+div).load('product'+div+'.html');
        $("ul.prodDetails li a").removeClass("prod1DetailsOn prod2DetailsOn prod3DetailsOn prod4DetailsOn");
        $("ul.prodDetails li.details1 a").addClass('prod'+div+'DetailsOn');
        $("#productsAll nav li a").removeClass("prodMainNav1 prodMainNav2 prodMainNav3 prodMainNav4");
        $(self).addClass('prodMainNav'+div);
        prodCarousel('#product'+div);
      }
    }):

$("#productsAll nav li.prod1 a").click(function(){
  prodNav("1", this);
  return false;
});

$("#productsAll nav li.prod2 a").click(function(){
  prodNav("2", this);
  return false;
});

});
```

It does not work. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Thanks,

Comment: What does 'It does not work'? What error(s) do you got? What doesn't work exactly? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: Explain "Does not work"?

Comment: Hint, "It does not work` is the most unhelpful way of explaining an error.  What doesn't work?  What was unexpected?  What DID you expect?  What behaviour does it exhibit?  See what I mean?

Comment: You click event handlers are outside of `$(document).ready()`.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this is the only issue, but this line:

```
$('#product'+div).load('product'+div+'.html');
```

is an asynchronous call.  It starts the loading of content in the product div.  But, later on in the same thread of execution, you call prodCarousel on that div and it looks to me like you expect the content to already be there.  It will likely not be there yet.

You will probably have to use a completion function on the load call and do the processing of that content after it has been successfully loaded like this.

```
$('#product'+div).load('product'+div+'.html', function() {
    // call prodCarousel() on the new content here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting a function inside $() is shorthand for document.ready().  ProdCarousel is being defined in the scope of an anonymous function - just move it outside of that.